# Error using windows service that connects to TFS Server using a TFS Token

Tags: c#, service, tfs

Here is the scenario.  I have written a windows service that connects to a project on a local TFS Server.  I created a TFS Token and am using that to log into the project so I can add items to the project.  I keep getting an error TF30063: You are not authorized to access https://***.***.***/DefaultCollection

Anyone have any idea what I am missing on this?

```
public void OnTimer(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs args)
    {            
        try
        {
            using (ExternalApiService externalApiService = new ExternalApiService
            {
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential { UserName = "*********", Password = "*******" }
            })
            {
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();


                conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=TFS; Initial Catalog=Tfs_DefaultCollection; Trusted_Connection=true";
                conn.Open();

                externalApiService.Url = "*****************";

                Search[] searches = externalApiService.listSearches(new ListSearchesRequest());

                long allOpenItemsSearchId = (from s in searches
                                             where s._searchName == "UJATFS items"
                                             select s._searchId).First();

                SearchRow[] allOpenItems = externalApiService.runSearch(new RunSearchRequest { _searchId = allOpenItemsSearchId });

                foreach (SearchRow searchRow in allOpenItems)
                {
                    int descriptionIndex = Array.FindIndex(searchRow._itemFields, w => w.fieldName == "Short Description");
                    int ticketNumberIndex = Array.FindIndex(searchRow._itemFields, w => w.fieldName == "Ticket Number");
                    int typeIndex = Array.FindIndex(searchRow._itemFields, w => w.fieldName == "Type");
                    int subCategoryIndex = Array.FindIndex(searchRow._itemFields, w => w.fieldName == "Subcategory");
                    int categoryIndex = Array.FindIndex(searchRow._itemFields, w => w.fieldName == "Category");
                    int statusDetailCodeIndex = Array.FindIndex(searchRow._itemFields, w => w.fieldName == "Status Detail Code");
                    int technicianNotesIndex = Array.FindIndex(searchRow._itemFields, w => w.fieldName == "Technician Notes");
                    int tfsCrossReferenceIndex = Array.FindIndex(searchRow._itemFields, w => w.fieldName == "TFS Cross Reference");
                    int ticketCrossReferenceIndex = Array.FindIndex(searchRow._itemFields, w => w.fieldName == "Ticket Cross Reference");
                    int priorityIndex = Array.FindIndex(searchRow._itemFields, w => w.fieldName == "Priority");
                    int locationIndex = Array.FindIndex(searchRow._itemFields, w => w.fieldName == "Location");
                    int fNameIndex = Array.FindIndex(searchRow._itemFields, w => w.fieldName == "First Name");
                    int lNameIndex = Array.FindIndex(searchRow._itemFields, w => w.fieldName == "Last Name");
                    int phoneIndex = Array.FindIndex(searchRow._itemFields, w => w.fieldName == "Phone Number");
                    int jobTitleIndex = Array.FindIndex(searchRow._itemFields, w => w.fieldName == "Job Title");
                    int createdDateIndex = Array.FindIndex(searchRow._itemFields, w => w.fieldName == "Created On");
                    int notesIndex = Array.FindIndex(searchRow._itemFields, w => w.fieldName == "Notes");

                    TeamFoundation tf = new TeamFoundation();

                    if (descriptionIndex >= 0)
                    {
                        if (((itemField)searchRow._itemFields[descriptionIndex]).fieldValue.Length > 0)
                        {
                            tf.Description = ((itemField)searchRow._itemFields[descriptionIndex]).fieldValue[0].ToString();
                        }
                    }

                    if (ticketNumberIndex >= 0)
                    {
                        if (((itemField)searchRow._itemFields[ticketNumberIndex]).fieldValue.Length > 0)
                        {
                            tf.TicketNumber = ((itemField)searchRow._itemFields[ticketNumberIndex]).fieldValue[0].ToString();
                        }
                    } 

                    if (typeIndex >= 0)
                    {
                        if (((itemField)searchRow._itemFields[typeIndex]).fieldValue.Length > 0)
                        {
                            tf.Type = ((itemField)searchRow._itemFields[typeIndex]).fieldValue[0].ToString();
                        }
                    }

                    if (subCategoryIndex >= 0)
                    {
                        if (((itemField)searchRow._itemFields[subCategoryIndex]).fieldValue.Length > 0)
                        {
                            tf.SubCategory = ((itemField)searchRow._itemFields[subCategoryIndex]).fieldValue[0].ToString();
                        }
                    }

                    if (categoryIndex >= 0)
                    {
                        if (((itemField)searchRow._itemFields[categoryIndex]).fieldValue.Length > 0)
                        {
                            tf.Category = ((itemField)searchRow._itemFields[categoryIndex]).fieldValue[0].ToString();
                        }
                    }

                    if (statusDetailCodeIndex >= 0)
                    {
                        if (((itemField)searchRow._itemFields[statusDetailCodeIndex]).fieldValue.Length > 0)
                        {
                            tf.DetailStatus = ((itemField)searchRow._itemFields[statusDetailCodeIndex]).fieldValue[0].ToString();
                        }
                    }

                    if (technicianNotesIndex >= 0)
                    {
                        if (((itemField)searchRow._itemFields[technicianNotesIndex]).fieldValue.Length > 0)
                        {
                            tf.TechnicianNotes = ((itemField)searchRow._itemFields[technicianNotesIndex]).fieldValue[0].ToString();
                        }
                    }

                    if (priorityIndex >= 0)
                    {
                        if (((itemField)searchRow._itemFields[priorityIndex]).fieldValue.Length > 0)
                        {
                            tf.Priority = ((itemField)searchRow._itemFields[priorityIndex]).fieldValue[0].ToString();
                        }
                    }

                    if (ticketCrossReferenceIndex >= 0)
                    {
                        if (((itemField)searchRow._itemFields[ticketCrossReferenceIndex]).fieldValue.Length > 0)
                        {
                            tf.TicketCrossReferenceNum = ((itemField)searchRow._itemFields[ticketCrossReferenceIndex]).fieldValue[0].ToString();
                        }
                    }

                    if (locationIndex >= 0)
                    {
                        if (((itemField)searchRow._itemFields[locationIndex]).fieldValue.Length > 0)
                        {
                            tf.Location = ((itemField)searchRow._itemFields[locationIndex]).fieldValue[0].ToString();
                        }
                    }

                    if (fNameIndex >= 0)
                    {
                        if (((itemField)searchRow._itemFields[fNameIndex]).fieldValue.Length > 0)
                        {
                            tf.FirstName = ((itemField)searchRow._itemFields[fNameIndex]).fieldValue[0].ToString();
                        }
                    }

                    if (lNameIndex >= 0)
                    {
                        if (((itemField)searchRow._itemFields[lNameIndex]).fieldValue.Length > 0)
                        {
                            tf.LastName = ((itemField)searchRow._itemFields[lNameIndex]).fieldValue[0].ToString();
                        }
                    }

                    tf.Requestor = tf.FirstName + " " + tf.LastName;

                    if (phoneIndex >= 0)
                    {
                        if (((itemField)searchRow._itemFields[phoneIndex]).fieldValue.Length > 0)
                        {
                            tf.PhoneNum = ((itemField)searchRow._itemFields[phoneIndex]).fieldValue[0].ToString();
                        }
                    }

                    if (jobTitleIndex >= 0)
                    {
                        if (((itemField)searchRow._itemFields[jobTitleIndex]).fieldValue.Length > 0)
                        {
                            tf.JobTitle = ((itemField)searchRow._itemFields[jobTitleIndex]).fieldValue[0].ToString();
                        }
                    }

                    if (createdDateIndex >= 0)
                    {
                        if (((itemField)searchRow._itemFields[createdDateIndex]).fieldValue.Length > 0)
                        {
                            tf.CreateDate = ((itemField)searchRow._itemFields[createdDateIndex]).fieldValue[0].ToString();
                        }
                    }

                    long itemID = 0;
                    GetItemDetailsRequest getItem = new GetItemDetailsRequest();

                    itemID = searchRow._itemId;

                    getItem._itemId = itemID;
                    getItem._itemDefinitionId = 10257;

                    TicketDetailsResponse detailsResponse = externalApiService.getTicketDetails(getItem);

                    DescriptionDetail[] detail = detailsResponse._allDescriptionsList;

                    int wo_num = 0;
                    string task = "";
                    string type = "";
                    string workOrderCrossReference = "";

                    Uri tfsUri = new Uri("https://***/DefaultCollection");
                    TfsConfigurationServer configurationServer =
                            TfsConfigurationServerFactory.GetConfigurationServer(tfsUri);

                    VssBasicCredential vssBasicCredential = new VssBasicCredential("", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TFSToken"]);

                    TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(tfsUri, vssBasicCredential);
                    teamProjectCollection.EnsureAuthenticated();

                    WorkItemStore workItemStore = teamProjectCollection.GetService<WorkItemStore>();


                    string projectName = "UJA";

                    Project teamProject = workItemStore.Projects[projectName];
                    WorkItemType workItemType = teamProject.WorkItemTypes["Service Desk Ticket"];

                    wo_num = tf.WONum;
                    type = tf.Type;
                    task = tf.Description;
                    workOrderCrossReference = tf.TicketCrossReferenceNum;

                    WorkItem userStory = new WorkItem(workItemType)
                    {
                        Title = task,
                        Description = "Requestor: " + tf.Requestor + ":  " + task
                    };

                    userStory.History = tf.TechnicianNotes;
                    userStory.Fields["Work Order Cross Reference"].Value = tf.TicketCrossReferenceNum;
                    userStory.Fields["Ticket#"].Value = tf.TicketNumber;
                    userStory.Fields["TrackIT Requestor"].Value = tf.Requestor;
                    userStory.Fields["TicketCreatedDate"].Value = tf.CreateDate;
                    userStory.Fields["TrackIT Location"].Value = tf.Location;
                    userStory.Fields["TrackIT Phone#"].Value = tf.PhoneNum;
                    userStory.Fields["TrackIT Job Title"].Value = tf.JobTitle;

                    //Get Status info for each work order number
                    //*******************************************************************
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.GetFtTFSStatus", conn);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    SqlParameter parm = new SqlParameter("p_status_detail", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    parm.Value = tf.DetailStatus;

                    cmd.Parameters.Add(parm);

                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    da.Dispose();
                    //********************************************************************
                    //userStory.Fields["State"].Value = "Proposed";
                    //userStory.Save();

                    //userStory.Fields["State"].Value = "Active";
                    //userStory.Save();

                    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        userStory.Fields["Area Path"].Value = projectName + "\\" + dt.Rows[0]["TFSAREA"].ToString();
                        userStory.Fields["State"].Value = dt.Rows[0]["TFSSTATE"].ToString();
                        userStory.Fields["Triage"].Value = dt.Rows[0]["TFSTRIAGE"].ToString();
                    }

                    //Get Priority info for each work order number
                    //*******************************************************************
                    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("dbo.GetFtTFSPriority", conn);
                    cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    SqlParameter parm2 = new SqlParameter("p_priority", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                    parm2.Value = tf.Priority;

                    cmd2.Parameters.Add(parm2);

                    DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();

                    SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
                    da2.Fill(dt2);
                    da2.Dispose();
                    //********************************************************************

                    if (dt2.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        userStory.Fields["Priority"].Value = dt2.Rows[0]["TfsPriority"].ToString();
                    }

                    //Get assigned user
                    //*******************************************************************
                    SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("Custom.spGetUserName", conn);
                    cmd3.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();

                    SqlDataAdapter da3 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd3);
                    da3.Fill(dt3);
                    da3.Dispose();
                    //********************************************************************

                    userStory.Fields["Assigned To"].Value = dt3.Rows[0]["TfsUserName"].ToString();

                    foreach (DescriptionDetail desc in detail)
                    {
                        userStory.History = desc._data;
                        userStory.Save();
                    }

                    userStory.Save();

                    LogService("Ticket#: " + userStory.Id.ToString());

                    //Put the TFS cross reference number into Footprints                        
                    long returnItem = 0;
                    bool returnBool = false;
                    string[] tfsData = new string[1];
                    tfsData[0] = userStory.Id.ToString();
                    string[] tfsDetailCode = new string[1];
                    tfsDetailCode[0] = "Closed";

                    EditTicketRequest editTicketRequest = new EditTicketRequest();

                    itemField[] items = new itemField[2];
                    items[0] = new itemField();
                    items[0].fieldName = "TFS Cross Reference";
                    items[0].fieldValue = tfsData;

                    items[1] = new itemField();
                    items[1].fieldName = "Status Detail Code";
                    items[1].fieldValue = tfsDetailCode;

                    editTicketRequest._ticketFields = items;

                    editTicketRequest._ticketId = itemID;

                    editTicketRequest._ticketDefinitionId = 10257;

                    try
                    {
                        externalApiService.editTicket(editTicketRequest, out returnItem, out returnBool);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        LogService("Error: " + e.Message);
                        continue;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            LogService(e.Message.ToString());
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: at least share some of your code, which will be very helpful for the viewers to understand the issue.

Comment: I am 100% sure the code isn't the problem.  It worked before.  I just changed the TFS Token and recompiled and now it doesn't work

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1772fab7-c37a-4425-9998-7cd82f285039/tf30063-you-are-not-authorized-to-access-from-c?forum=TFService

Comment: This did not work for me.

Comment: You **should not** be querying the TFS database directly. It's completely unsupported, likely to break between versions, and will be guaranteed not to work if you ever want to move to Azure DevOps and migrate to the cloud. Use the provided REST APIs to ensure you have a path forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
Uri tfsUri = new Uri("https://tfs.courtswv.gov/DefaultCollection");
var networkCredential = new NetworkCredential(String.Empty, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TFSToken"]);
VssBasicCredential vssBasicCredential = new VssBasicCredential(networkCredential);
VssCredentials tfsCredentials = new VssCredentials(vssBasicCredential);
TfsTeamProjectCollection tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(tfsUri), tfsCredential)
tpc.Authenticate();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: The last line I changed to what you have and it worked.  Don't know why that changed since all I was changing was the TFS Token.